# Optional multiselect field, hide the - None- option

Tags: forms

I am working on a form made mostly of multi-select fields, which are optional for the user to choose.

The multi-select fields work fine in general; however I really need to hide the *-None-* option in the multi-select fields which are not required for user to select. I can override it and change the text but thats not the point, since user can still select the *-None-* value in the process of selection, even tho it wont show after node is saved.

It just looks a bit confusing, even though it works as it should; users can select both the *-None-* option along with other options available and that makes the whole form different from what I want.

Here is an image of an example field showing what I mean.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

I tried searching through the CCK module, but I couldn't really find anything.

Comment: @rishariss What happens in your scenario if someone actually selects an item from the drop down then wants to back out of it? Forcing them to reload the page and start again is far worse UX than what you're explaining

Comment: Could you answer question from my first comment: "is it Form API form, Webform, Quick Form?.." Without that data it's simply impossible to help you. And yea, we know you don't want him to select none and something. All we wanted to know is how you plan to allow them unselect all options. Checkboxes in dropdown are nice way to do so :)

Comment: Im using standard CCK method under manage fields of content type to add fields. To be more exact it's a term refference field with select list widget and multiple values avaliable. 
Then to change the look and usability of it, i used the jquery ui multi-select widget. I hope i answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of "- None -" from selected field of a selected form, use:

```
function MYMODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    unset($form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options']['_none']);
}
```

Of course for many fields it's inconvenient, but if they all share common parent (fieldset), you can iterate using `foreach` like:

```
function MYMODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    foreach( element_children($form['fieldset_name']) as $key => $child) {
       unset($form['fieldset_name'][$key][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options']['_none']);
    }
}
```

This is not a ready code, just a sketch. Hints to make it work:

1. Unset elements of original `$form`, not `$child` generated by `foreach`.
2. Test if what you want to unset is there at all.
3. `dpr()` or `var_dump()` to see what's the exact structure you are working with.

You will need to wrap these into a Drupal custom module. Read [Module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules), especially [Creating Drupal 7 modules](http://drupal.org/node/361112), and [`hook_form_alter()` API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) if you need more backgroung.

Inspired by [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36524/rename-none-option-for-select-list-field-type#36529).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mołot! Im really new to php and that code is not fully understandable to me yet, but i will certainly do some research and try to make it work.

Comment: @rishariss updated answer with some links that will give you basics needed to use that code in Drupal. PHP coding is something I hardly can't help you with, you need to know it to modify Drupal's internals.

Comment: Big thanks! I resolved my issue by creating new module and using the code which you suggested earlier. I used a sparete unset for each field individually, even tho im pretty sure there is a better way to do it, still, it works!.




`function MYMODULE_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    unset($form['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#options']['_none']);
}`

Comment: @rishariss if works, consider accepting my answer ;) You should see tick under vote arrows. If you will, people looking for this issue will know your question was answered in  a helpful way, so they will read it and get what they need.

Comment: you missunderstood me, ofcourse im accepting it, i just meant that i could probablly target all fields in one line instead of targeting em in each individual line separately if i knew what i was doing :) Once again, big thanks! best regards

Comment: @rishariss experiment with [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel). Use `dpr($form);` to see form structure. And, well, experiment. That's the best way to learn IMO. Good luck.