# Using hook_form_alter() to add the "None" value in the select list of a required field

Tags: forms, hooks

When a field is required, Drupal removes the default "-None-" value.  However, also for a required field, "-None-" is very valuable as it requires the user to make a deliberate selection (put the first value on the select list as default doesn't force a sloppy user to make a selection).

I need to:

- Have "-None-" as default value in the select list of a required field
- Not accept "-None-" as field value when the form is submitted

How can I achieve this with `hook_form_alter()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename "-none-" option for select list field type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36524/rename-none-option-for-select-list-field-type)

Answer (score 2):

By default, the label for the first default option is automatically set to "- Select -" for a required field and "- None -" for an optional field. To force the `#empty_option` to also show "- None -" for a required field, assign it with something like:

```
"#empty_option" => t('- None -'),
```

This will keep everything else intact and will do exactly what you want. See [`class Select`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Select.php/class/Select/8.2.x).

Comment: Hello @leymannx.  This is indeed the general rule.  However, this does not apply to all select fields.   In some cases, I don't see the "-Select a value-" as default option for a select list : an entity reference, the country field of the address module.  Any idea on how to tackle these (perhaps I should update my question accordingly? Sorry, I'm new to stack exchange...)